# Start multiple jars from Jenkins Scripted Pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, jenkins-pipeline, executable-jar

I am trying to run some integration tests in Jeknins against two different jars. The problem is that I want to manipulate the start/stop of jars from Jenkis script and I don't know how exactly.

For the moment I have something like this:

```
   stage('Start ZZ&ZZT') {
      dir('workingdir') {
         sh 'java -jar zenzefiT.jar'
         sh 'java -jar zenzefi.jar'
      }
   }
```

This is not woorking properly as the first jar is started and then hanged.
If I do something like this,

```
   stage('Start ZZ&ZZT') {
      dir('workingdir') {
         sh 'java -jar zenzefiT.jar &'
         sh 'java -jar zenzefi.jar &'
      }
   }
```

the jars are not started.

I would like a solution to start the jars (maybe like waiting for the jars to start properly and then continue), have another stage where I can run some tests and then stop the jars (this can be done by killing the processes by ports I guess).
I tried as well with shell scripts on the machine.

Please help,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution already for those interested. Also added a check to be sure that the app starts correctly.

```
   stage('Start ZZ&ZZT') {
      dir('workingdir') {
         withEnv(['JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKill']) {
            sh 'java -jar jar1.jar &'
            sh 'java -jar jar2.jar &'
         }
         def isZZTrunning = sh(returnStatus:true, script: 'sudo lsof -t -i:62000')
         while(isZZTrunning == 1) {
            isZZTrunning = sh(returnStatus:true, script: 'sudo lsof -t -i:62000')
            echo "Waiting for Jar1 to start"
            sleep(time: 1, unit: "SECONDS")
         }

         def isZZrunning = sh(returnStatus:true, script: 'sudo lsof -t -i:61000')
         while(isZZrunning == 1) {
            isZZrunning = sh(returnStatus:true, script: 'sudo lsof -t -i:61000')
            echo "Waiting for JAr2 to start"
            sleep(time: 1, unit: "SECONDS")
         }
      }
   }
```